# Rails, gmaps4rails, bootstrap and turbolinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, gmaps4rails

Firstly, I read other threads on SO about Google Maps, turbolinks etc. but they do not work for me (or I am doing something wrong).

I have a page with bootstrap tabs - one tab displays 1st partial, and the second one displays the partial with the Google Map included.

After I switch to the second tab the map stays blank all the time (grey screen). It appears after I inspect the page (or hide the inspect) in google chrome.

My question is what might be causing it (turbolinks?) and how should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this:

```
var mapRefreshed = false;
  $('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
    $(this).tab('show');
    if ($(this).is("#map_view_tab") && (mapRefreshed == false)) {
      console.log("Map refreshed!");
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
      mapRefreshed = true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  })
```